# Increase Openfire connection pool - maximum connections

Tags: connection, openfire

I have Openfire 3.7.1 install on Linux (RHEL). How I could increase maximum connections?
Current values: Maximum Connections: 25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-2056)

> The default maximum connection limit (in the absence of any
>   configuration) is 10.   In the openfire.xml configuration file, in the
>   `<defaultProvider>` section, add the following tags to set minimum and
>   maximum connection limits.

```
<minConnections>5</minConnections>
<maxConnections>25</maxConnections>
```